# NSArray with several Keys to TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I've a weather app I'm working on.  I get the Forecast data pulled in, which has an `NSArray` for each day of the forecast.  The array looks like this:

```
(
        {
        apparentTemperatureMax = "73.44";
        apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467500400;
        apparentTemperatureMin = "47.12";
        apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467457200;
        cloudCover = "0.75";
        dewPoint = "43.53";
        humidity = "0.58";
        icon = rain;
        moonPhase = "0.9399999999999999";
        ozone = "276.53";
        precipIntensity = "0.0036";
        precipIntensityMax = "0.0092";
        precipIntensityMaxTime = 1467504000;
        precipProbability = "0.44";
        precipType = rain;
        pressure = "1015.28";
        summary = "Light rain starting in the afternoon.";
        sunriseTime = 1467460332;
        sunsetTime = 1467513207;
        temperatureMax = "73.44";
        temperatureMaxTime = 1467500400;
        temperatureMin = "47.12";
        temperatureMinTime = 1467457200;
        time = 1467439200;
        windBearing = 281;
        windSpeed = "0.54";
    }
)
```

I take all the days and combine them into one giant `NSMutableArray`.  What I want to do is to take that `NSMutableArray` for the Source of the `UITableView`, but only put in some of the weather data, like temperatureMin, temperatureMax, precipProbability, and so on.  What would be the best way for me to take the `NSMutableArray` which houses several arrays, and only display some bits of information from each of those?

UPDATE:

Here is the full NSMutableArray:

```
(
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "73.44";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467500400;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "47.12";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467457200;
            cloudCover = "0.75";
            dewPoint = "43.53";
            humidity = "0.58";
            icon = rain;
            moonPhase = "0.9399999999999999";
            ozone = "276.53";
            precipIntensity = "0.0036";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0092";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1467504000;
            precipProbability = "0.44";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1015.28";
            summary = "Light rain starting in the afternoon.";
            sunriseTime = 1467460332;
            sunsetTime = 1467513207;
            temperatureMax = "73.44";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467500400;
            temperatureMin = "47.12";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467457200;
            time = 1467439200;
            windBearing = 281;
            windSpeed = "0.54";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.59";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467576000;
            apparentTemperatureMin = 56;
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467540000;
            cloudCover = "0.41";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "45.21";
            dewPointError = "10.53";
            humidity = "0.55";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.97";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1016.93";
            pressureError = "1.78";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467546762;
            sunsetTime = 1467599598;
            temperatureMax = "69.59";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.68";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467576000;
            temperatureMin = 56;
            temperatureMinTime = 1467540000;
            time = 1467525600;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = "1.98";
            windBearing = 217;
            windBearingError = "38.17";
            windSpeed = "6.24";
            windSpeedError = "4.9";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.69";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467662400;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "55.94";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467622800;
            cloudCover = "0.39";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "45.61";
            dewPointError = "9.890000000000001";
            humidity = "0.55";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.02";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.46";
            pressureError = "1.74";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467633192;
            sunsetTime = 1467685988;
            temperatureMax = "69.69";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.69";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467662400;
            temperatureMin = "55.94";
            temperatureMinError = "9.48";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467622800;
            time = 1467612000;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = 2;
            windBearing = 216;
            windBearingError = "35.68";
            windSpeed = "6.72";
            windSpeedError = "4.83";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.78";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467748800;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "56.03";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467709200;
            cloudCover = "0.39";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "45.91";
            dewPointError = "9.67";
            humidity = "0.5600000000000001";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.05";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.36";
            pressureError = "1.7";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467719624;
            sunsetTime = 1467772376;
            temperatureMax = "69.78";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.65";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467748800;
            temperatureMin = "56.03";
            temperatureMinError = "9.470000000000001";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467709200;
            time = 1467698400;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = 2;
            windBearing = 215;
            windBearingError = "35.59";
            windSpeed = "6.7";
            windSpeedError = "4.8";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.84999999999999";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467835200;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "56.11";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467795600;
            cloudCover = "0.4";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "46.2";
            dewPointError = "9.470000000000001";
            humidity = "0.5600000000000001";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.08";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.26";
            pressureError = "1.67";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467806058;
            sunsetTime = 1467858761;
            temperatureMax = "69.84999999999999";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.57";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467835200;
            temperatureMin = "56.11";
            temperatureMinError = "9.41";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467795600;
            time = 1467784800;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = 2;
            windBearing = 214;
            windBearingError = "35.54";
            windSpeed = "6.67";
            windSpeedError = "4.77";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.91";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1467921600;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "56.17";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467882000;
            cloudCover = "0.41";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "46.47";
            dewPointError = "9.32";
            humidity = "0.57";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.12";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.16";
            pressureError = "1.63";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467892492;
            sunsetTime = 1467945146;
            temperatureMax = "69.91";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.449999999999999";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1467921600;
            temperatureMin = "56.17";
            temperatureMinError = "9.300000000000001";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467882000;
            time = 1467871200;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = 2;
            windBearing = 213;
            windBearingError = "35.55";
            windSpeed = "6.63";
            windSpeedError = "4.74";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.95999999999999";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1468008000;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "56.23";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1467968400;
            cloudCover = "0.41";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "46.71";
            dewPointError = "9.23";
            humidity = "0.57";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.15";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.08";
            pressureError = "1.6";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1467978927;
            sunsetTime = 1468031528;
            temperatureMax = "69.95999999999999";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.31";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1468008000;
            temperatureMin = "56.23";
            temperatureMinError = "9.17";
            temperatureMinTime = 1467968400;
            time = 1467957600;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = "2.01";
            windBearing = 212;
            windBearingError = "35.64";
            windSpeed = "6.57";
            windSpeedError = "4.71";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.98999999999999";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1468094400;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "56.26";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1468054800;
            cloudCover = "0.42";
            cloudCoverError = "0.35";
            dewPoint = "46.94";
            dewPointError = "9.18";
            humidity = "0.57";
            humidityError = "0.19";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.18";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1017.01";
            pressureError = "1.58";
            summary = "Partly cloudy throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1468065364;
            sunsetTime = 1468117908;
            temperatureMax = "69.98999999999999";
            temperatureMaxError = "9.17";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1468094400;
            temperatureMin = "56.26";
            temperatureMinError = "9.029999999999999";
            temperatureMinTime = 1468054800;
            time = 1468044000;
            visibility = 10;
            visibilityError = "2.01";
            windBearing = 211;
            windBearingError = "35.84";
            windSpeed = "6.48";
            windSpeedError = "4.68";
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: please share your Full response, then i have help you

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: The best way is to only add what you'll use in the first place. But don't expect any huge performance gains - it might be simpler to just leave it how it is now, and don't use what you don't need.

Comment: I think @IyyappanRavi means you should share your full HTTP response (the forecast data), not just one element of the array. I.E., what's the structure of your "NSMutableArray which houses several arrays"?

Comment: I added the full NSMutableArray

Comment: Try to share your json response it will be more helpful.

Comment: yes share your NSMutableArray Value.

Comment: @user717452 see my answer its helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to use array in the source of table.

1- you can get the value from the array - 
Ex-

```
NSString * temperatureMax_Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"temperatureMax"]];
```

2- create a NSDictionary and add the value from array -

```
NSDictionary *Dic = [Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString * temperatureMax_Str = [Dic  valueForKey:@"temperatureMax"];
```

Some other ways also there , You can try that also like creating mutable dictionary etc.

Comment: Option #1 gives me this:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fea795b8820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

Comment: may be your (array.count - 1) < indexpath.row ...
Check it first . or your key is not same .

Answer (score 0):

Use this Single line Code your `cellForRowAtIndexpath`,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    sampleTableCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCellIdenfier"];
    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.temperatureLabel.text = [[[YourArrayName objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"temperatureMax"];

    return cell;
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Trying that gives me this:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fea795b8820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

Comment: You set class name is wrong, check your class in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model object, e.g. `WeatherObject` class and parse your response into an array of this kind of objects. Discard any fields you feel like discarding during parsing. After you can set the `NSMutableArray` of `WeatherObject`s as data source for your table view. This would be much more object-oriented and human-readable code.